# Two queries returned different result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with SQL queries. I have two nearly identical queries that differ just that the first one returns only one column, `id`, and the second one returns all columns, `*`. Queries are as follows:

Query 1:

```
SELECT id 
FROM `import_data` 
WHERE 1 AND parent IS NULL 
ORDER BY CONCAT(category_1, COALESCE(category_2, ""), COALESCE(category_3, "")) DESC;
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `import_data` 
WHERE 1 AND parent IS NULL 
ORDER BY CONCAT(category_1, COALESCE(category_2, ""), COALESCE(category_3, "")) DESC;
```

Each query has a different order of results, even though I have specified the same `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Can you post the result.

Comment: actually it is rather obvious

Comment: In both query resultset notice the `id` column; if they are in same order then it's absolutely fine.

Comment: Add CONCAT(category_1, COALESCE(category_2, ""), COALESCE(category_3, "")) to the SELECT list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would get different orders if you have multiple rows where `CONCAT(category_1, COALESCE(category_2, ""), COALESCE(category_3, ""))` are the same.

*How does SQL order rows where the key values are the same?*  The answer is that the ordering is arbitrary and can change from one query to the next.  SQL does *not* guarantee stable sorts, meaning that the order of the final sort, when there are ties, is indeterminate.

I would suggest that you just add `id` to the `order by` clause:

```
ORDER BY CONCAT(category_1, COALESCE(category_2, ""), COALESCE(category_3, "")) DESC, id
```

If `id` is unique, then the two queries will return the same order.

Comment: Typo, remove ; between DESC and , id.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's functional.

Comment: I have finally dared to edit @Gordon Linoff answer and removed the `;`